# Bind textbox with response from onclick event - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, view

I have a textbox in my view page. when i click on imageIcon,it will take data from db and return in alert successfully. But, when i try to bind this response data to textbox, it is not binded correctly. My code in view page is as following :

```
@foreach (var dateitem in list)
                    {                        
                            <td id="HoursTxt">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(modelitem => dateitem.Hours, new { id = string.Format("txtHours"), style = "width:50%;height:70%;" }) 
                                @Html.Hidden("CuDate", dateitem.Date)
                                    <img src="~/Images/comment.png" class="prevtest" />
                                <div style="border:solid;display:none;">                                   
                                    <input type="text" id="TxtNotess" />
                                    <input type="button" id="BtnComment" value="Save" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
             }
```

In my onclick event of imageIcon jquery is following:

```
$('.prevtest').on('click', function () {        
        var Cudate = $(this).prev('#CuDate').val();
        var ProjId = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
        var TskId =parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td').find('#testTaskId').val());       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Timesheet/GetComments?ProjectId=" + ProjId + "&TaskId= " + TskId + "&date= " + Cudate,
            success : function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                $('#TxtNotess').val(data);
                alert('success');
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

the text box with id TxtNotess not bind with response value
Can anyone help me to do this..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.prevtest').on('click', function () {
    var Cudate = $(this).prev('#CuDate').val();
    var ProjId = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
    var TskId = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td').find('#testTaskId').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Timesheet/GetComments?ProjectId=" + ProjId + "&TaskId= " + TskId + "&date= " + Cudate,
        context: this,//pass a custom context to the ajax handlers - here the clicked element reference
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('.TxtNotess').val(data);//find the target textfield
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

I gets resolved by using class name for textbox..

Answer (score 2):

First: ID of an element must be unique so use class for the textfield `TxtNotess`.

```
<input type="text" class="TxtNotess" />
```

Then, in the success handler find the textfild with class `TxtNotess` inside the next sibling of the clicked element

```
$('.prevtest').on('click', function () {
    var Cudate = $(this).prev('#CuDate').val();
    var ProjId = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val());
    var TskId = parseInt($(this).parents('tr').find('td').find('#testTaskId').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Timesheet/GetComments?ProjectId=" + ProjId + "&TaskId= " + TskId + "&date= " + Cudate,
        context: this,//pass a custom context to the ajax handlers - here the clicked element reference
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $(this).next().find('.TxtNotess').val(data);//find the target textfield
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. I tried it but still textbox is empty after click event

Comment: whether the data is alerting properly... also try to alert `$(this).length` in the handler

Comment: in alert i have got the data properly

Comment: is there problm because of for each loop ?

Comment: what about `alert($(this).length)` in the success handler

Comment: what about `alert($(this).next().length)` and `alert($(this).next().find('.TxtNotess').length)`

Comment: alert($(this).next().length) = 1 and alert($(this).next().find('.TxtNotess').length)=0

Comment: $('.TxtNotess').val(data);   now it's working.. Thanks . But i have one more doubt. The onclick event of button 'BtnComment' inside the div, is not working. is there any other way

Comment: `<input type="button" class="BtnComment" value="Save" />` then `$('.BtnComment').click(function(){})`